# Why does this IF statement fail?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

If variable `path` is empty, and `editor.Text` is not empty, the SaveFileDialog should be displayed.

Now, why on earth is this damn thing failing???

I have tried this with many different variations of code with the same result: FAIL:

```
if(path.Length >= 1) // path contains a path. Save changes instead of creating NEW file.
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
else
{
   // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }
}
```

At the top of code file I have:

path = String.Empty;

So why the heck it this failing every single time, even after trying all of the below variations?

```
if(path.Length > 1) // path contains a path. Save changes instead of creating NEW file.
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
else
{
   // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) // path contains a path. Save changes instead of creating NEW file.
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
else
{
   // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) // path contains a path. Save changes instead of creating NEW file.
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
else
{
   // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }
}
```

This is making me very angry. How could this fail?

Setting a break point reveals that `path` is *definitely* `null`/`""`.

Comment: Just to be clear: when you say "fail", you mean that path is either empty or null, but the else branch is being executed?

Comment: You also mention `and editor.Text`.  Are you sure it's not the editor that's causing the if to fail?

Comment: What do you mean by fail? Is the else statement NOT executing?

Comment: Can you change the condition and check , i.e if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(editor.Text))) 
{// no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }   
}
else
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}

Answer (score 5):

Why you've written:

```
if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogButtons.OK)
```

Instead of:

```
if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: Yeah Visual Studio was not responding so I couldn't copy/paste so I just decided to write it in here. I got confused :)

Answer (score 2):

If `path` is `null`, you're going to get an exception when trying to get `path.Length`. To check for an empty path, use the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)` version. You also need a condition to check your second requirement.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) // path contains a path. Save changes instead of creating NEW file.
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
else if (!String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(editor.Text))
{
   // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
   using(SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
   {
      if(saver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the path is a string and its the fullpath to your file? if its filled then it doesnt mean that the file really exists, you better go that way:

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{

}
else
{

}
```

File.Exists(null) returns false, so this will work fine

if you wanna use your way, then i guess your last two statements are just missing a "!"

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) 

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
```

check if null before access the length property

```
if(path != null && path.Length > 1)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to check if the file exists. I know how to do that too. But thanks.

Comment: your welcome, check my edit. i guess you just missed a not before asking if empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(editor.Text))
 {
       // no path defined. Create new file and write to it.
       using (SaveFileDialog saver = new SaveFileDialog())
       {
            if (saver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                 File.WriteAllText(saver.Filename, content);
            }
       }                
  }
  else if(File.Exists(path)
  {
       File.WriteAllText(path, content);
  }
```